# .NET EntityFramework: “An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

when I trie to save data with EF, asp.net fires an exception:
.NET EntityFramework: “An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details”

see my code bellow:

```
                foreach (tbCliente itemCliente in listClienteAtual)
                {
                    itemCliente.cod_usuario = idUsuarioAtual;
                    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(itemCliente, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                }
```

Comment: Did you "See the inner exception for details"?

Comment: so what's in the inner exception????